# ios Swift:How to compare object that existing in mutable array

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

Actually i'm new person for swift, this is my first project with swift.i have a problem faced that i cant compare the values with contains(),this is my code -- var str = "Dear"

```
    if addstatus.contains(str) {
        print("yes")
    } else {
        print("no")
    }
```

For this code it suggest a error ,pls find the screenshot

[image]

Anyone can help me,thanks in advance :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **containsObject** method for checking object exist in NSMutableArray

```
var myArray: NSMutableArray = ["one", "two", "three"]

  if myArray.containsObject("one") {
     print("yes")
  } else {
    print("NO ")
  }
```